# Visual indicator in List View to show if there are more items in the list

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll

I've a horizontal List View consisting of folder type nodes. At a time only 8 items are visible. If there are more items then an user has to scroll through the ListView to see the hidden content. I want to place a visual indicator to show if there are more items in the List or not.

In View pager, you can tilt the page if current page is last page. Is there a similar mechanism available for ListView. If not similar then which visual indicator should I use?

Comment: Have you tried this attribute `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack`

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah This will always show the scrollbar. In my listView the scrollbar is not visible even if I'm scrolling. I dont want scrollbar, is there other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `addFooterView` to show an `ImageView` at the bottom that there is more data and `removeFooterView` when you reach the end of the data. Another solution is to create a custom `ListView` and override `onDraw` to draw a down arrow for e.g. above the `ListView` if the list has not reached the end of the data.